# Unwanted repetition in output from java loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I am writing a code to reshape the signals. I am getting the output with unwanted repetitions.

INPUT:

> String[] rani = {"A","1","2","OK","B","3","4","OK","B","1","3","OK"};

Required OUTPUT:

> A/3 B/7 B/4

Got OUTPUT:

> A/3   A/3   A/3   A/3   B/7   B/7   B/7   B/7   B/4

ALGORITHM: Single alphabet strings ("A","B" etc.) are followed by number strings ("1","2" etc.). Each alphabet string is to be followed by slash and total of the numbers, and string "OK" is to ignored.

Being newcomer to java and programming I need help to get the needed output.

My code is:

```
public class SignalOK {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String finalSignal = "";
        String netSignal = "";
        String name = "";
        int total = 0;
        String[] rani = { "A", "1", "2", "OK", "B", "3", "4", "OK", "B", "1",
                "3", "OK" };

        for (int i = 0; i < rani.length; i++) {

            if ((rani[i] == "A") || (rani[i] == "B")) {

                name = rani[i];
            }

            if ((rani[i] == "1") || (rani[i] == "2") || (rani[i] == "3")
                    || (rani[i] == "4")) {

                total = total + Integer.valueOf(rani[i]);
            }

            if (rani[i] == "OK") {

                netSignal = name + "/" + String.valueOf(total) + "   ";
                name = "";
                total = 0;
            }
            finalSignal = finalSignal + netSignal;
        }

        System.out.println(finalSignal);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: Side note: replace the string concatention in loops with StringBuilder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the final result string concatenation inside the `"OK"` if brackets:

```
if (rani[i].equals("OK")) {
    netSignal = name + "/" + String.valueOf(total) + "   ";
    name = "";
    total = 0;   
    finalSignal = finalSignal + netSignal;
}
```

Also, always use `.equals()` to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach :-

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] inputString = {"A","1","2","OK","B","3","4","OK","B","1","3","OK"};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : inputString)
        sb.append(s); // creating a String from array contents
    String ss[] = sb.toString().split("OK"); // split on the basis of 'OK'
    sb.setLength(0); // emptying the sb, so that it can be used later on also
    for(String s : ss){
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        sb.append(ch[0]); // first alphabet like 'A','B','C'
        int val = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i< ch.length ; i++)
            val +=Integer.parseInt(""+ch[i]); // calculate the int value
        sb.append("/"+val+" "); // finally appending alphabet with int value
    }
    System.out.println(sb); 
}
```

Output :- `A/3 B/7 B/4`